# Recursion not returning expected result

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following recursion method:

```
def permute(instr, idx):
    if 'X' not in instr:
        yield ''.join(instr)

    for i in range(idx, len(instr)):
        if instr[i] == 'X':
            for j in ['0','1']:
                instr[i] = j
                permute(instr, i)
                instr[i] = 'X'
    

print(list(permute(list('10X01X'), 0)))
```

but the result is yielding `[]`.  If I instead change the `yield` statement to a `print` statement, I in fact get the correct results being printed to the screen.  I can overcome this with a "global" variable, like so:

```
def run_permute():
    global_arr = []

    def permute(instr, idx):
        if 'X' not in instr:
            global_arr.append(''.join(instr))

        for i in range(idx, len(instr)):
            if instr[i] == 'X':
                for j in ['0','1']:
                    instr[i] = j
                    permute(instr, i)
                    instr[i] = 'X'
        

    permute(list('10X01X'), 0)
    return global_arr
```

But I don't understand why I have to resort to this. Why doesn't my initial recursion method yield the correct results?

Comment: You aren't actually yielding anything from the recursive call; you need something like `yield from permute(instr, i)`.

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't run; `instr[i] = j` is a type error because you can't assign into a `str` value like this.

Comment: @chepner yeah, sorry, see Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield` works exactly like `return`, excepts that it essentially can return multiple values. If you replace `yield` in your code with `return`, you still do not get a return value (you now get `None`). This is because you aren't returning the value that your recurse function to the outside caller. You need to also add `return` to the line where you are doing the recursion.

In the same `yield` does not automatically propagate through the call stack, so with `permute(instr, i)` you are actually throwing away the results. You need to use `yield from`:

```py
def permute(instr, idx):
    if 'X' not in instr:
        yield ''.join(instr)

    for i in range(idx, len(instr)):
        if instr[i] == 'X':
            for j in ['0','1']:
                instr[i] = j
                yield from permute(instr, i)
                instr[i] = 'X'
```

Imagine these two functions instead:

```py
def a():
    yield "A"

def b():
    a()
    yield "B"
```

If you know look at `list(b())`, you only see one entry, `"B"`, since the return value of `a()` isn't used. If you instead do:

```py
def a():
    yield "A"

def b():
    yield from a()
    yield "B"
```

You get `["A", "B"]`

Comment: @Megalng that fixed it. I don't understand why though.

Comment: Do you need more help?

Comment: Adding the `yield from` solves it. I'll mark your answer as correct once SO lets me. Would you mind elaborating a little on that? I thought yielding works similar to a `return`, but returns a generator that continues to yield once that `yield` statement is reached

Comment: @David, better know?

Comment: @Megalng: much better, thanks, I really appreciate it.